# Remove braces from AppendTo output

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the following inside a loop:

`tts={};
AppendTo[tts, p]` where p is just a number at each iteration so that in the first iteration I get: `{0.844908}`, in the second `{0.844908,0.830764}`, in the third `{0.844908,0.830764,0.820169}` and so on.

How can I flatten the output of `AppendTo` as to obtain in each iteration the number(s) only without `{}`?

Comment: try `Row[{0.844908, 0.830764, 0.820169}, ","]`

Comment: You can remove the braces by `Apply`ing `Sequence`: `Sequence@@AppendTo[tts, p]`. This replace the current `Head` of the return valus of `AppendTo` with `Sequence`. However, I wonder what you want to do with that. If you want to supply the numbers to another function `f`, you can do that directly with `f@@AppendTo[tts, p]`.

Comment: But overall, using `AppendTo` is often problematic, as it involves a copy of the whole list. If the list has `n` elements, then `AppendTo` needs $O(n)$ time an memory. You might want to learn about `Sow` and `Reap` (see documentation) or about ``Internal`Bag`` (undocumented, search this site).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thank you so much. This works great! And thanks for the recommendations !

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun!